# Unified and transparent pointer events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-touch

I have a bootstrap `.btn` that I want to toggle with the mouse click. The problem is that the response is way too slow on tablets, since the `click` arrives 300 ms after the `touchstart` in mobile browsers.

I tried binding the logic in the `touchstart` event, effectively breaking the app for desktop browsers where there is no `touchstart`. I then thought of binding the same logic also to `click` but then I get a repeated event in mobile browsers. I've juggling around, trying to unbind from `click` the first time I receive a `touchstart`, and so on, and managed to come up with a design so complicated that there is always some quirk here or there that I cannot solve.

For instance, I can't get a text input to receive focus in the tablet: if I do focus on `touchstart` then the `click` event returns the focus to the button. I tried jQuery Mobile's `vmousedown`, but I couldn't manage to have multi-touch (tapping more than one button at the same time only changed one of them). I don't want to reinvent a lot of wheels, and I'm sure I must be missing something obvious, either on jQuery Mobile, or plain JavaScript.

In concrete, I want an event like `vmousedown` that works both on desktops and mobiles, only fires once on each, and allows multi-touch.

Comment: use the Modernizr library. `if(Modernizr.touch){ //logic here }else{ //no touch event }`

Comment: Is it jQuery compatible?

Comment: Yes, Modernizr is compatible with jQuery.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy would please write an answer with a little more detail, so that I could accept it? I would like to know how to handle both the case for mobiles and desktops. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for handling actions based on the device, etc. It provides great cross-browser/platform support without the need to sniff User Agents and the like. Instead, it uses feature detection.

You can just use the Modernizr functions with jQuery's `$(document).ready(function()});`

```
$(function(){
    if (Modernizr.touch){
       // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
    } else {
       // bind to normal click, mousemove, etc
    }
});
```

This code has been taken straight from the [Modernizr Documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

[Also, here's another resource](http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/touch.html) for performing `touch tests`

Comment: Great !!, I'll wrap it all into a `$.fn.pointerDown` function that lets me bind to either `mousedown` or `touchstart` transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but note that jQueryMobile also has similar touch detection:
    if ( $.mobile.support.touch ) {...
And no, IMHO, you are not missing anything obvious :), cross-platform / cross-device / touch-friendly features are still harder than they should be. For example, today I'm looking at a win8 surface tablet: touch-screen and a mouse. There are cases where i'd like to know which device was used. event.originalEvent.type should differentiate between tap and click, right? wrong :(.